# How to call static method from inside of a class body?

Tags: python, class, subclass, static-methods, class-method

Let's assume I have a class, with a static method, and I want a class property to be set to the value that this method returns:

```
class A:
    @staticmethod
    def foo():
        return 12

     baz = foo()
```

But doing this I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in A
TypeError: 'staticmethod' object is not callable
```

I found a way to get around this:

```
class A:
    class B:
        @staticmethod
        def foo():
            return 2
baz = B.foo()
```

But for example if I write:

```
class A:
    class B:
        @staticmethod
        def foo():
            return 2

    class C:
        baz = B.foo()
```

I also get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in A
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in C
NameError: name 'B' is not defined
```

Is there a way to call static methods from within a class while declaring it?
Why 1st and 3rd examples of code does not work but 2nd does? How python interpretor handles such declarations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `staticmethod` is a descriptor.  A descriptor exposes the `__get__(instance, cls)` method allowing it to be accessed either through an instance or at the class level.

Now in your case you wish to call it within a class stanza.  Normally this would not be possible as neither an instance nor the class are yet available.  However a `staticmethod` ignores both in any case so you can use the following rather nasty approach to call it.

```
class A:
    @staticmethod
    def foo():
        return 12

    baz = foo.__get__(None, object)()
```

Then

```
>>> A.baz
12
```

**Note:**  The only reason to pass `object` as the second argument is that `staticmethod` insists on being passed a class of some kind as the second argument.

Answer (score 1):

This is also a workaround, but it might help.

In the `class` body you cannot refer to the class being created. OTOH a class decorator receives an initialized class, thus it can call its methods directly.

```
def add_baz(cls):
    cls.baz = cls.foo()
    return cls 

@add_baz
class A:
    @staticmethod
    def foo():
        return 12
```